# How to print QR Code to bluetooth printer using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

How to print QR Code to bluetooth printer using flutter?
i'm using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial this package but i dont know how to print qrcode from my unique ID

I tried method writeBytes but i dont know convert from my unique ID string to Qr Code to print

```
String foo = 'TEST';
List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(foo);
bluetooth.writeBytes(bytes);
```

i dont know convert from string to qrcode bytes to bluetooth printer

Comment: `ZXing` is often used, looks like there is an unofficial [Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/fzxing) available.

Comment: it for scan qrcode or print qrcode ?

Comment: Both! Everything to do with qr / barcodes

Comment: oke. but how to generate qr code ? give me example please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [blue_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer) or [bluetooth_print](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print) library.
With these libraries you can printQR Code to bluetooth printer

Comment: Which devices support these libraries?

Comment: @AliCanSahin which you need?

Comment: YuLinca B21, thanks.

Comment: I found a good repo about it. https://github.com/AndBondStyle/niimprint